# Redirect output with '>&!'

Tags: command-line, redirect, io, csh

I know that `>&` means redirect stderr to stdout.

But I don't know the meaning of `>&!`, I tried following command but it seems like normal.

Example:

```
cat xxx.txt >&! xxx.output
```

My environment is `csh` shell and `ubuntu18`.

Could someone teach me this, thanks.

Comment: Please give us some context. Where did you get this from? Did you try?

Comment: @pLumo I tried. But nothing changed.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you have a question like this, the answer will almost certainly be in the manual. I just run `man csh` and then pressed / to search, entered `&!` and then enter. That took me to the relevant section:

> > name
> >! name
> >& name
> >&! name
>
> The file `name` is used as standard output.  If the file does not exist then it is created; if the file exists, it is  truncated, its previous contents being lost.
>
> If the shell variable `noclobber` is set, then the file must not exist or be a character special file (e.g., a terminal or `dev/null`) or an error results. This helps prevent accidental destruction of files.  In this case the `!` forms can  be
> used  to suppress this check. If `notempty` is given in `noclobber`, `>` is allowed on empty files; if `ask` is set, an interactive confirmation is            presented, rather than an error.
>
> The forms involving `&` route the diagnostic output into the specified file as well as the standard output. `name` is expanded in the same way as `<` input filenames are.

So, the quoted section explains `csh`'s redirection operators. To summarize the above, `>` redirects to a file and `>!` forces the redirection to occur even if the user has set the `noclobber` option which normally blocks you from redirecting to an existing file. The `&` redirects standard error as well as standard output, so `>&!` will redirect both stderr and stdout to a file, overwriting any content the file may have even if the `noclobber` option is set.

Answer (score 1):

Note, this answer is for `bash`, not for `csh` like OP added afterwards.

---

`>&` does **not** mean *redirect stderr to stdout* (which would be `2>&1`), it means redirect stderr+stdout to something.

And in your case, `!` is the something.

---

From GNU Bash Reference Manual >> [Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html)
>> **3.6.4 Redirecting Standard Output and Standard Error**:

> This construct allows both the standard output (file descriptor 1) and the standard error output (file descriptor 2) to be redirected to the file whose name is the expansion of word.
>
> There are two formats for redirecting standard output and standard error:
>
> ```
> &>word
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> >&word
> ```
>
> Of the two forms, the first is preferred. This is semantically equivalent to
>
> ```
> >word 2>&1
> ```

So, `&>!` will redirect stdout+stderr to a file called `!`.

Note, that both versions are GNU bashisms, only the last version (`>word 2>&1`) is Posix compliant.

Also be careful, `!` will invoke [history expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3747/understanding-the-exclamation-mark-in-bash) if something follows.

Comment: I tried `cat xxx.txt >&! xxx.output`, and I found `xxx.output` generated.

Comment: Cannot confirm this, which shell do you use? Which Ubuntu version?

Comment: I use shell `csh` and 18.04.

Comment: Okay, this would have been very important information regarding it is not the default in Ubuntu ... Please edit your question ...